# Inequalities with cubic polynomials

Tags: inequality, polynomials

So I was checking my friend's notes and found this:

Find the interval for which $x^3-x^2-x+1>0$ is true.

We haven't been taught to factor cubic polynomials (the rest of the exercises are with second degree ones), yet without any process or hesitation my friend writes $(-1, 1)\cup(1,\infty)$ as an answer. With second degree polynomials, we were taught to find the values of $x$ for which the expression equals zero and then see how it behaves near those values to find whether the expression is positive or negative.

Could anyone help me out? Is this the actual answer and, if it is, how did he do it so fast without factoring?

Comment: He/she probably factored, or noted there is a double root at $1$ and another at $-1$. The factorization is easy in this case, for our polynomial is $x^2(x-1)-(x-1)$.

Comment: $ \ (x^3 - x - x^2 + 1) \ = \ (x^3 - x) - (x^2 - 1) \ = \ (x - 1) \cdot (x^2 - 1) \ = \ (x-1) \cdot (x-1) \cdot (x+1) \ . $ [I've been working all week with students learning factoring.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this factorization, $ \ (x^3 - x - x^2 + 1) \ = \ (x-1) \cdot (x-1) \cdot (x+1) \   $ , we see that there are two values of $ \ x \ $ where the polynomial value is zero.  This divides the real numbers into three intervals:  $ \ x < -1 \ , \ -1 < x < +1 \ , \ x > + 1 \ . $

The factor $ \ (x - 1)^2 \ $ is *always* positive (when it isn't zero), so the sign of the polynomial value is "controlled" entirely by the factor $ \ (x + 1) \ . $  So the polynomial is negative when $ \ x < -1 \ $ and positive for $ \ x > -1 \ , $ except at $ \ x = +1 \ . $  Thus the inequality holds on $ \ ( -1 , +1 ) \ $ and on $ \ (+1 , +\infty) \ . $

If your friend *didn't* factor, (s)he may have just tried some small integers in the polynomial and noticed where the sign of the value changed, or when the value *is* zero.  (It isn't too hard to do this when the coefficients of the polynomial are *small* integers...)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm guessing he tried a few integers close to zero and figured it out.